# Cannot find module `mysql` node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

i am a newbie to nodejs. To connect mysql, i installed `mysql` on node using the command,

```
npm install mysql
```

I didn't get any error while installing. Then i tried executing the following code,

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
```

But it is showing the following error while im trying to execute that.

```
C:\node\mysql>node app.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node\mysql\app.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

I tried some suggestion like installing mysql globally using,

```
npm install -g mysql
```

But nothing works. Help please!!!

Please note my working environment,

OS: Windows7
Node version: 0.10.15
NPM version: 1.3.5

Comment: Are you running your script from the same directory you ran `npm install mysql`?

Comment: Also, using `npm install -g` is global install.

Comment: @MorganARRAllen How to run it on the same directory?

Comment: Try running `npm ls` from that same directory that app.js is in. This will list out the npm modules that are installed for that project.

Comment: @JaimeMorales It is showing 

 mysql@2.0.0-alpha8
── bignumber.js@1.0.1
── require-all@0.0.3

under the tree

Comment: @Udhay, do you get that same error when you go into the node REPL (from within that directory), and type `var mysql = require('mysql')`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem and found it was because the module was installed in:

`./node_modules/node-mysql/node_modules/`

So, I just moved them all:

`mv ./node_modules/node-mysql/node_modules/* ./node_modules/`

Comment: I installed it more than one time using npm install -g mysql but I get :/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mysql# ls node_modules
bignumber.js  readable-stream  require-all, I don't find node-mysql, please advise about the path to do the above, because it doesn't work

Comment: I use the mysql2 2.2.5 version which does not have cardinal but the helper.js requires for the cardinal as below. How to solve this?

Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'cardinal' from '\node_modules\mysql2\lib'
required by node_modules\mysql2\lib\helpers.js

Answer (score 15):

```
npm install mysql --save
```

This will update your package.json file.

Answer (score 11):

My `node` is installed in `C:\some-dir\nodejs-0.10.35\`

First navigate to the same directory `node` installed: `cd C:\some-dir\nodejs-0.10.35`

Then `npm install mysql`

I put my applications in the same directory: `C:\some-dir\nodejs-0.10.35\applications\demo.js`

It works.

Comment: I use the mysql2 2.2.5 version which does not have cardinal but the helper.js requires for the cardinal as below. How to solve this?

Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'cardinal' from '\node_modules\mysql2\lib'
required by node_modules\mysql2\lib\helpers.js

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you might be confused about how `npm install` works.

`npm install -g mysql` will install globally not locally like you suggest.

`npm install mysql` will install locally, putting the module in `./node_modules/mysql`. This means the script you are running needs to be run from the same directory containing `node_modules`.

Answer (score 7):

You can fix this with

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules /YOURPROJECTFOLDER/node_modules
```

Comment: for me, this one really get past the error "Cannot find module 'mysql'"

Comment: Actually, the other way around `ln -s /YOURPROJECTFOLDER/node_modules /usr/local/lib/node_modules` worked for me (Debian 10)

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue (granted I am on Windows 8).  I tried `npm install mysql` and `npm install -g mysql` and neither worked.

Turned out I needed to open the 'Node.js Command Prompt' app rather than the regular command prompt app.  Everything worked great.

I don't know what their command prompt does under the hood but I would assume it has something to do with pathing and environment variables.  You may want to give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You might have to update the package.json file. Use the following command

```
npm install mysql --save
```

Comment: This [exact same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46333364/542251) was added a full 5 months before you added this one.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Here is how solved it.

1. First created a proj dir e.g (Users/home/proj)
2. Go to then proj folder.
3. Run `npm init`  (this will create packaje.json).
4. Run (`npm install mysql`)
5. Check in proj folder, you should see node_modules folder, expand node_modules and you should see mysql folder.
6. Run your app.js

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install mysql2 --save
```

and require this one

```
var mysql = require("mysql2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to folder `/node_modules` which is inside the main directory, and install mysql by hitting the following command: `sudo npm install mysql`

This will create a folder called `mysql` inside the `/node_modules` folder.

Now run your app using `node app.js` command inside the main folder. It shall work and establish the connection with mysal server.

Answer (score 0):

I have same error, just run

```
npm install
```

will fix the problem. Sometime due to some reason, mysql package was damaged, or deleted, or missing, just run above will fix everything.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that on `npm install -g mysql` has saved mysql2 in node_modules. Just changed

```
require('mysql')
```

to

```
require('mysql2')
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

- go to your project folder
- run the following command: `npm install mysql`

Answer (score 0):

npm install MySQL --save

This is because you have not install MySQL in your package. You are importing this without installing MySQL in your system environment

Answer (score 0):

if using package.json, simply add below and run "npm install" in your project.

{ "dependencies": { "mysql": "2.12.0" } }

Answer (score -1):

I have found this happens if you run 
    npm install
without having dependencies defined in your package.json ... i.e.

```
...
"author": "Author",
"dependencies" : {
     "mysql": "2.12.0",    
},
"license": "ISC"
...
```

Define the dependecies .. then run

```
npm install
```

Comment: [`npm install mysql --save`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48753298/542251) will add this dependency for you without you having to edit the file manually