# Unable to find DLL files on internet. Any suggestions

Tags: node.js, canvas, dll

I am not sure if the question depicts everything, but here is the story.

I needed a canvas for my node.js project thus I downloaded it following the instructions from node-canvas github. When, I compiled and run my program, I got this error

> ```
> >module.js:355
> >Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
>                            ^ Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
> ```
>
> C:\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node
>       at Error (native)
>       at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>       at require (module.js:384:17)
>       at Object. (C:\node_modules\canvas\lib\bindings.js:2:18)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)

FYI, this is not an error from my code as  I only get this when I include the canvas module in my script.
I had already set the path variable, downloaded 64bit GTK, updated Visual C++ Redistribution Packages for Visual Studio 2013  and still was getting the above error.
My quick search online made me use dependency walker which said following dll are missing

API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL

API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL

API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHUTDOWN-L1-1-1.DLL

EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL

I was able to found the first 3 dlls but could not found last 2 anywhere. I am using win8.1 64bit,

Please any suggestion how can I get those file. If it is not possible to get them, then any suggestion on how can I use canvas in node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved the above problem?

1) The reason I was unable to include canvas module in my project file is due to the wrong installation. Following the instructions from this post, [Cannot find module `mysql` node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134411/)
 I put my project folder under node and installed the module there.

2) I don't think above dll files actually has to do with this problem. When I solved the problem, I ran the dependency walker again on the same file and again it was showing the same dll missing. Seems, it is something with Windows 8.1.