# There is an error in running mysql (node.js) file in cmd

Tags: mysql, node.js

There is an error in running  `mysql` (node.js) file in cmd. It is showing module not found...

What is the problem occurring?

Please help....

The error:-

```
C:\Users\mhars>node trial.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:926
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\mhars\trial.js'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:923:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:768:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module \`mysql\` node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134411/cannot-find-module-mysql-node-js)

Comment: Could you please update your question with the exact command line output? That'd be helpful.